# Click on "use" element Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on a button on ifunny.co using Python selenium, but the button isn't a button element, it's a "use" element. The code I usually use can't click this button. Please help. (I tried the click method two different ways). Also, I'm not sure if the "xlink:" is included in the attribute, but it doesn't work as "xlink:href" or "href". How do I click this button?

```
try:
    content = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//use[@xlink:href, '#icon_grid-full-size-active')]")))
    content.click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//use[@xlink:href, '#icon_grid-full-size-active')]").click()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to execute click via javascript and execute_script driver function, like:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//use[@xlink:href, '#icon_grid-full-size-active')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: I got to my solution with another response mixed with the one from Vova:       
`element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='use' and @*='#icon_grid-full-size-active']")))                            
        for i in element:                                                     
            i.click()`